# Зеркало сайта на разных серверах

Tags: домен, зеркало, хостинг

Доброго времени суток,#ХэшКод

Предположим у меня:
 1. есть сайт с доменным именем site.ru на отдельном сервере А
 2. есть сайт с доменным именем site.com на отдельном сервере B

Один сайт является точной копией второго, доменный регистратор и хостер для обоих сайтов одинаковы.
Можно ли сделать, чтобы при недоступности **site.ru**(например из за DDOS), юзер при попытке открыть **site.ru** перенаправлялся на **site.com**?

Спасибо за внимание

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего для обоих доменов запихнуть одни и те же айпишники в [round robin dns](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round_robin_DNS) (хоть я никогда и не работал с ним). Упавшая наглухо машина все равно ничего не скажет пользователю, даже если каким-то образом настроить сервак на обработку ошибок от апстрима.